# There is no schemaregistry.bat file inside Confluent Platform. What is the solution to it?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I have to create a message breaking system with consumer groups in **Avro Serialized** Data Format via Scala.
For **avro** serialization I need **schema registry** which is not available in windows compatible file.
Can someone help ?

Comment: Confluent don't officially support Schema Registry on Windows. The official recommendation is to run it in Docker if you have to use Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure which version of Confluent Platform you downloaded, but there definitely is a start batch script

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/bin/windows/schema-registry-start.bat

Or if you're using Windows 10, you could use WSDL with the Unix scripts, and if not, you could even try Cygwin.

Otherwise, Docker, a VM, or Confluent Cloud would work

Comment: Did you really need Cygwin? That `schema-registry-start.bat` script works in CMD for me

Comment: Actually my version of confluent.io was not having a bat file for schema-registry but cygwin helped me to run the linux compatible file in windows.

Comment: Not clear what version you were using, but that script is open source... https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/tree/master/bin/windows